# Xml creation using ElementTree

Tags: python, xml

I am new to python. I want to create a xml tree with one parent, several childs and several subchilds. I've stored child tags are in list 'TAG' and Subchild tags are in list 'SUB' 
And i have came up with following code but i am not able to achieve the desired result !

```py
def make_xml(tag,sub):
'''
Takes in two lists and Returns a XML object.
The first list has to contain all the tag objects
The Second list has to contain child data's
'''
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, Comment, tostring
top = Element("Grand Parent")
comment = Comment('This is the ccode parse tree')
top.append(comment)
i=0
try:
    for ee in tag:
        child = SubElement(top, 'Tag'+str(i))
        child.text = str(tag[i]).encode('utf-8',errors = 'ignore')

        subchild = SubElement(child, 'Content'+str(i))
        subchild.text = str(sub[i]).encode('utf-8',errors = 'ignore')

        i = i+1;
except  UnicodeDecodeError:
    print 'oops'
return top
```

EDIT:
I have two lists like these:
TAG = ['HAPPY','GO','LUCKY']
SUB = ['ED','EDD','EDDY']

What i want is:

```
<G_parent>
    <parent1>
         HAPPY
        <child1>
              ED   
        <\child1>
     <\parent1>
     <parent2>
         GO
        <child2>
              EDD
        <\child2>
    <\parent2>
    <parent3>
         LUCKY
        <child3>
              EDDY
        <\child3
    <\parent3>
<\G_parent>
```

The actual list has many more contents than this. I want to achieve using a for loop or so.

```
EDIT:
```

OOP's. My bad ! 
The code works as expected when i pass the example list. But in my real application the list is long. The list contains text fragments extracted from a pdf file. Somewhere in that text i get UnicodeDecodeError(reason: pdf extracted text messy. Proof: 'oops' get printed once ) and the returned xml object is incomplete.
So I need to figure out a way that even on UnicodeDecodeErrors my complete list is parsed. Is that possible ! I'm using .decode('utf-8',errors='ignore') even then the parsing does not complete !

Comment: What is the expected result? As I see this returns xml with elements and subelements.

Comment: Please edit your original post to show a small amount of what you want to encode, and how it should look.

Comment: See [this article](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/03/15/processing-xml-in-python-with-elementtree/), especially the **Building XML documents** section.

Comment: @DonQuestion: thanks, but you are unlikely to see me do that any time soon, as I'm the maintainer of etree in stdlib :)